# Unable to find error while inserting data into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Can some one here tell me what is wrong with my code? Benn spending like an endless hour finding the error.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CarReserve(UserName,Manufacture,Model,Plate,DateReturn,TimeReturn) Values (@Username1,@Manufacture1,@Model1,@Plate1,@Date1,@TimeReturn1)", conn);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username1", Label1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacture1", Label3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model1", Label4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plate1", Label5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datel", Label6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeReturnl", Label7.Text);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Redirect("HomeUser.aspx"); 

}
```

The error is must declare the scalar var @Date1. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datel", Label6.Text);
```

Looks like you typed `@Date**l**` 'Letter ell' instead of `@Date**1**` 'Number one'.

It also looks like you made the same mistake with the following line as well:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeReturnl", Label7.Text);
```

Answer (score -1):

As well as I know that you should put parameters and it's values before the sql query string  like:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection  (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username1", Label1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacture1", Label3.Text);

cmd.CommandText = "Insert into CarReserve(UserName,Manufacture,Model,Plate,DateReturn,TimeReturn) Values (@Username1,@Manufacture1,@Model1,@Plate1,@Date1,@TimeReturn1)";

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```